# Multi-thread web crawling with Crawler4j: Missing pages

Tags: java, web-crawler, scrapy, crawler4j

I am using multi-thread crawler `Crawler4j` to crawl some websites. This crawler allows the user to define the number of threads of the crawler to be run on a website. I decided to run the crawler up to `depth/layer = 10` and crawl up to `501 pages per depth`. With this setup, I run the crawler with `# of threads set to 1` and then `# of threads set to 5`. For one website, I have recorded the `layer number` and `# of pages crawled in that layer`. The data is as follows-

```
**Crawler with 1 thread**
Layer: 0 frequency: 0
Layer: 1 frequency: 41
Layer: 2 frequency: 306
Layer: 3 frequency: 416
Layer: 4 frequency: 501
Layer: 5 frequency: 501
Layer: 6 frequency: 199
Layer: 7 frequency: 113
Layer: 8 frequency: 6
Layer: 9 frequency: 0
Layer: 10 frequency: 0

**Crawler with 5 threads**
Layer: 0 frequency: 0
Layer: 1 frequency: 41
Layer: 2 frequency: 268
Layer: 3 frequency: 384
Layer: 4 frequency: 501
Layer: 5 frequency: 501
Layer: 6 frequency: 338
Layer: 7 frequency: 501
Layer: 8 frequency: 501
Layer: 9 frequency: 501
Layer: 10 frequency: 501
```

The first two layers went fine-the frequency of webpages crawled for those two layers are the same. But from that point I see some differences. My question is: is it possible to have differences in the frequency data for the two runs (with 1 thread and with 5 threads)? And if yes, what is the logic behind it and if no, what can cause this?

Comment: Same timespan for both runs?

It could be possible, that the frontier in the 1-threaded run is processed in a different way than the 5-threaded run (since the 5 threads share the same frontier).

Comment: I don't understand how you did your test, did you addSeed() in runtime ?

Comment: Please provide more details about your test setup!